# Set MaxLength for dynamic <p>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script which allows to display Bing search results. I can call for the search results url's like this:

```
'<p class="width"><a  href="' , imgResult.Url , '">',imgResult.DisplayUrl,'</a></p>' ,
```

The problem is that sometimes the url is to long an 'sloppy' like this:

```
http://www.art-wallpaper.net/Game-Wallpapers/Assassins-Creed-Brotherhood/imagepages/image3.htm
```

I would like to 'hide' or 'delete' the beginning of the url (`http://www.`) and do the same from  `/Game...` etc This way I can get a 'clean' and 'short' url like: `art-wallpaper.net` I there a (simple) way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a JavaScript function like this.

```
function shorten(str)
{
   // Get rid of the protocol
   str = str.replace("http://", "");
   str = str.replace("https://", "");

   // Return the domain-part of the URL
   return str.split("/")[0];
}
```

Pass your URL to the JavaScript function prior to printing it.

**Untested.**

Answer (score 0):

```
url="http://www.art-wallpaper.net/Game-Wallpapers/Assassins-Creed-Brotherhood/imagepages/image3.htm";
    pathArray =url .split( '/' );
    host = pathArray[2];
    alert(host);// alert "www.art-wallpaper.net"
```

and,

```
    pathArray = "http://www.art-wallpaper.net/Game-Wallpapers/Assassins-Creed-Brotherhood/imagepages/image3.htm".split( '/' );
host = pathArray[2].substring(4);
alert(host);// alert "art-wallpaper.net"
```

​